# Add data to JSON File best practice

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm a UI designer in a product company and we design UI for different features and minor upgrades. we then host it on a local server and share it with the concern developers. It has become clumsy now as we have a lot of projects in it and it's quite hard to find the right files. We thought of building a simple index.html file which will be accessed locally by anyone. I have a JSON file which contains the info abt the projects, used AJAX to dynamically build UI with JSON data, now I wanna add an "add task" btn which will add new task form data in JSON file. what is the best practice to follow?

Comment: you could simply use JavaScript on that button `click` and push the data into the JSON .

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa but will it work if the client and server computers are different? I heard it will not work unless we have a server side program which can handle. sorry if this sounds stupid, Im totally new to coding.

Comment: You mean to say the json file is in a server(not in your local) ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Yes! every file will be on the server computer hosted by apache and every one of us can access using a name:port

Comment: In that case you will also need some server side code. It is a **2 step process** - You need to first pass the value to be added to the backend(using api etc.). The backend code will then take those data and update the json file. That function has to be created just once at the server side.